# UIStatusBarStyle changes after displaying a UIWindow over UIStatusBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwindow, uistatusbar

I am displaying a UIWindow over the `UIStatusBar`, by default the `UIStatusBarStyle` is set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`, but when I display the `UIWindow` the `UIStatusBarStyle` switches to the black style.

Comment: check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671359/uistatusbar-changes-style-for-no-apparent-reason/19674047#19674047

Comment: @David G. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 16):

I came across this topic while struggling with the same problem. What you have to do is create a new view controller and set it as the root view controller of your `UIWindow` (that is the `UIWindow` that you are displaying over your other view). Then, in this new view controller implement the `preferredStatusBarStyle` method like this:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" property in Info.plist to NO and implement the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]` method as Azabella suggested. However, this will set the Status Bar of all your views to white. If that's no problem, then there's no need to make a separate view controller just to set the `preferredStatusBarStyle` method.

Comment: In my case, i alloc a new UIWindow to show a content over all views including the status bar, then i never the the preferredStatusBarStyle called again using setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate. Then i cant change the status bar color. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you created a root viewController for this new UIWindow, as suggested above?

Comment: I also needed to override prefersStatusBarHidden to false, without it the statusbar was hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" property in yourAppName-Info.plist to NO ?

Answer (score 1):

This was a fairly trivial problem that I found to be resolved setting `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` to `true`.

Comment: Where would you set modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance to prevent the overlay UIWindow from capturing the status bar appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Add this so when the view appears it will set the colour/style

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```