# UIStatusBar changes style for no apparent reason

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uistatusbar

I have an app in which I set the `UIStatusBarStyle` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and it works perfectly fine for a while. Then, as suddenly than unexpectedly, it changes to `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` for no apparent reason.

`View controller-based status bar appearance` property is set to `NO`.

Is there a specific place which I should set the `UIStatusBarStyle` in? Currently I set it in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` before anything else.

Thank you very much for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set .plist file like :

[image]

write each view-controller :

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
  if [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;// for black color 
  }else
  {
     return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;// set as default
  }
}
```

Hope it will help.

happy coding...