# dimming iOS7 statusbar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, statusbar

I'm developing an iPhone app that (only) shows a datepicker when the user is to select a date. When the datepicker is shown, the rest of the screen will dim, so there's more visual focus on the date picker. This effect is currently achieved by adding a partially opaque black button at the size of the screen, and adding the `datePicker` as a subview. No problem so far.

The problem is that the statusbar isn't affected. Because my statusbar is white, it only becomes more notable as the rest of the screen darkens. I want the statusbar to be dimmed / darkened as well.

I have seen an app that exactly does what I want. I searched a lot, but I don't know how to achieve it. Is there any way to set the opacity of the statusbar or to overlap it with another view?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Status bar as in the one with the signal strength, time, and battery level?

Comment: Why not hide the status bar when you show your date picker, then show it once the a date is selected?

Comment: @MarcusAdams That value is deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Why don't you try putting `UIDatePicker` inside `UIActionSheet`? It'll automatically dim the rest of the screen.

Comment: @Cojoj Alert views or action sheets cannot contain custom content, especially on iOS7.

Comment: @LeoNatan hiding statusbar is an option, thank you for suggesting. I will try reecon's answer first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple. What you need to do is create a `UIWindow` with `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` level. This will overlap the status bar. Here is sample code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.7f];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You can add views to this window. They can even overlap the status bar. Remember to store a reference to the new window otherwise it will be deallocated.

If you want to control the status bar appearance, or get information about rotation events you should create a `UIViewController` and set it as a `rootViewController` of your winndow. Then if you want to change the status bar style to light, add this code in the view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle 
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: The window **must** be retained or otherwise will be removed. The system does not retain windows. Also, adding subviews to a window is quite difficult, as rotation support drops to the developer. A root view controller, on the other hand, is best of both worlds.

Comment: @LeoNatan, thanks for feedback. I added to my answer part about retaining the window. I disagree that adding subviews is difficult. It's as easy as calling `addSubview:`. Indeed we're loosing rotation support but sometimes we just don't care about it (if we only support e.g. portrait mode).

Comment: No reason not to use a root view controller with a view (even the date picker itself!). It will even be transparent. No reason to limit rotation.

Comment: I tried your and  @LeoNatan 's UIWindow solution. I can definitely see that this is the way to to achieve what I want. However, when I display the UIWindow, the statusbar color changes to black. Same issue here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617122/uistatusbarstyle-changes-after-dispaying-a-uiwindow-over-uistatusbar). Any ideas?

Comment: @Tuslareb, to change status bar style you need to create a `UIViewController` and set it as a `rootViewController` of your window. Then, you have to implement the `preferredStatusBarStyle` method to change status bar style. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here.

1. Hide the status bar. This is the simplest - hide it, display your picker, select date, show the status bar, hide the picker. What more, if you put show and hide in the same animation block as the date picker show/hide, it will animate in sync.
2. Use a window for your picker with a level of `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1` as @reecon suggests. This complicate matters little, but not much. From experience, I recommend using a simple view controller with either your content view directly, or a root clear color view to hold the content view. You can animate the window by `[UIView transitionWithView:window duration:0.3
   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations: ^ {
   [window makeKeyAndVisible]; } completion:nil;`. Remember to retain the window, or you will not even see it, as it is deallocated; windows are not retained by the system. **Take a look at my [`LNWindowManager`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNWindowManager) library for an even easier window presentation API.**
3. Show an overlay window on top of the statusbar frame only. This is a little easier to maintain, as you can just resize the window to the status bar frame whenever the status bar frame changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at [`RMDateSelectionViewController`](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController) which gives you the ability to pick data in `UIActionSheet` style (so the backgroud is dimmed).

Comment: I took a look at that project but it doesn't dim the statusbar. Just like my app, it uses a semi transparent black view to cover the main view. When using a white status bar it becomes apparent that the black view doesn't cover the statusbar.